# PLSQL - Cursor for a recursive sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a recursive sql query, it looks like this:

```
WITH goes(from_, to_) AS 
 (
  SELECT from_, to_ FROM ways
   UNION ALL
  SELECT ways.from, goes.to_ FROM ways, goes
  WHERE ways.to_ = goes.from_ AND ways.from_ <> goes.to_
 )
 CYCLE from_ SET is_cycle TO 'I' DEFAULT 'N' 
 SELECT  distinct from_, to_ FROM goes order by 1
```

I want to write a plsql procedure, which can handle the output of this query as a cursor, but I don't know how to start it.

Can you please help me a little? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you are having - you can use this as a cursor query like you could any other query; why is it being a recursive CTE an issue?

Comment: @AlexPoole - I guess what may be confusing is the WITH clause (recursive or not). Of course, it works as is - once one has tried it and has seen how cleanly it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "handle". Simplest is an implicit FOR cursor:

```
for rec in 
  (
     with goes as ....... order by 1
  )
loop
   -- enter processing commands here
end loop;
```